# How to change DataGridColumn Border element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to change the border(I mean component) BrushColor based on the value in the DataGrid column(see screen). I think I am just missing some stupid thing...
[How it should see for example when Type of Alarm is High](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE2dX.png)
Edit:
Marked in App.xaml which BorderBrush I want to change
I have tried:

```
<DataGrid 
                    RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle2}"
                    Name="AlertTable"
                    Grid.Row="5"
                    BorderBrush="{Binding TypeOfAlert , Converter={StaticResource CellConverter}}" // Got 
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Viditelný"
                    >
<DataGrid.DataContext>
                        <local1:CellConverter/>
                    </DataGrid.DataContext>
<!-- ---- -!>
<DataGrid />
```

> Second try, but it works just for TextBlocks!:

```
<DataGridTextColumn
                            Header="Type of Alert "
                            Width="*"
                             Binding="{Binding TypeOfAlert}"
                            >
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style 
                                    TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
                                    >
                                    <Setter
                                        Property="Background"
                                        Value="{Binding TypeOfAlert , Converter={StaticResource CellConverter}}"
                                        >
                                        
                                    </Setter>
                                    
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
```

> in App.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Transparent" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                            <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"  
CornerRadius="5" 
///I want change this BorderBrush
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                    
                                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <DataGridCellsPresenter ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                    <DataGridDetailsPresenter Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                                    <DataGridRowHeader Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                
                            </Border>
                            
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

A DataGridColumn does not have a BorderBrush (or Border-anything) property. In your first code block, you set the BorderBrush for the whole DataGrid, which is probably not what you want at all. As I understand it, you want to set the border of each DataGridRow, which means you need to set the binding in the RowStyle.

Comment: No DataGrid does not have BorderBrush Property, but in DataGridRowStyle Border has

Comment: I added App.xaml template

Comment: @Shawn_Medinsky DataGrid does have BorderBrush and BorderThickness properties, and the former is what you're setting in your first code block.

Comment: Yeah, But I don't want to change DataGrid BorderBrush, but row. I will mark it in my question.